# fetch pertocular data from url xml of amazon product Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, lookup, amazon-product-api

I am new to asp.net and working on amazon product advertising API look up........ I want to  fetch the price of the product from the API.They have generated me the URL which is generating the XML contains the details of the product.I only want to fetch the amount from "amount" node.I have tried for many days but could not do it.Can any one help me.Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

**REST** way

Download file from (AmazonProductAdvtApiSampleCSharpQuery\Sample\src) from https://aws.amazon.com/code/Product-Advertising-API/2480 and copy SignedRequestHelper.cs

```
 SignedRequestHelper helper = new SignedRequestHelper("XXXXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "webservices.amazon.com");

 IDictionary < string, string > dictValue = new Dictionary < string, String > ();
 dictValue["Service"] = "AWSECommerceService";
 dictValue["Version"] = "2011-08-01";
 dictValue["Operation"] = "ItemLookup";
 dictValue["ItemId"] = asinCode;
 dictValue["IdType"] = "ASIN";
 dictValue["AssociateTag"] = "xxxxxxxxx-xx";
 dictValue["ResponseGroup"] = "ItemAttributes";

 string url = helper.Sign(dictValue)
 WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
 string price;

 using(WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync()) {
    if (response != null) {

        using(XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(response.GetResponseStream())) {
            // Now parse XML  accordingly

            reader.ReadToFollowing("ListPrice")
            if (reader.ReadToDescendant("FormattedPrice")) {
                price = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
```